# Trying to start sqlalchemy database but got an error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, freesqldatabase

This is showing in my vs-studio terminal:

```
>>> from app import db #this command is running successful.
>>> db.create_all() # this command not running.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\Practice\Flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1039, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')

  File "D:\Python\Practice\Flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1031, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)

  File "D:\Python\Practice\Flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()

  File "D:\Python\Practice\Flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 555, in get_engine
    options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)

  File "D:\Python\Practice\Flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 570, in get_options
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)

  File "D:\Python\Practice\Flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 883, in apply_driver_hacks
    if sa_url.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

Comment: Could you provide the code where you define `db` and `app`?

Comment: app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite://///todo.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    desc =  db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.sno} - {self.title}"

Comment: Why there `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite://///todo.db"` are five `/`? It should be `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:////todo.db"`

Comment: Why do you set `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to `False` then?

Comment: SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to False => because when, i was not using this at that time my terminal was showing command to set it TRUE or FALSE that's why i used it.

Comment: I assume you are not right and you have received this message: `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.`. Remove this string `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = False` anyway and fix the previous string also to `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:////todo.db"`

Comment: @DilipSahu Please use [edit] button, don't post your code in comments.

Comment: i followed your step, but i still got same error.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you define `db` and `app` again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66729624/15425742

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmaU9.png

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite://///todo.db" app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = False app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False`

remove this line code:

`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = False`

Try this lines of codes:

`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db' app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False`

And for VSCode terminal:

`>>> import app`

`>>> from app import db`

`>>> db.create_all()`